# Parsing JSON with Dynamic Field with Gson and Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 to access an API, and I'm having trouble parsing the responses into objects in a flexible way.

The API responses are in this general format:

```
Request: /api/users
Response:
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Get all users",
    "users": [{
        "id": 1
        "name": "User Name"
    }]
}

Request: /api/user/1/items
Response:
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Get all items",
    "items": [{
        "id": 1
        "name": "Item Name"
    }]
}
```

The models are generally formatted as such:

```
data class ApiResponse<T>(val success: Boolean,
                          val message: String,
                          val payload: T)
data class User(val id: String, val name: String)
data class Item(val id: String, val name: String)
```

I have tried using an `okhttp3.Interceptor` to parse the response, but I just can't figure out how to handle the key being dynamic (users, items, etc). I know the key when I'm making the request, but I'm not sure how to communicate that to my Intercepter in order to get the value from the JSON.

Comment: You will want to look at creating a `custom json deserializer`. Then when you get to an `items` or `users` you can create the object that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use @SerializedName("message") val message: String, and so on.

Comment: This won't work because there are many more types of data that could be sent in the response. I don't want to have a class that has fields for all of the possible responses.